# If condition in a return statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a if statement with in a function that returns multi-values. I tried this but it's not working.

```
a(this).attr('src', function(i, current){
    if ( i == 'http://www.old.com'){
        return current.replace('http://www.old.com','http://www.new.com');
    }
    else if ( i == 'http://www.older.com'){
        return current.replace('http://www.older.com','http://www.new.com');
    }
    else ();
});
```

Comment: why do you have an empty else block?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `else{}`? Or better yet, just leave it out altogether?

Comment: When you say `return`, do you want to replace the value of the `src` attribute?

Comment: This is jQuery, yes?  Don't you mean `if(current == 'http://www.old.com')`?

Comment: I assume the result of the `a(this)` call is a jQuery object. Is that correct? Should this also be tagged `jquery`?

Comment: @apsillers: I'm just assuming it's jQuery.  It could be another library.

Comment: @RocketHazmat True. (To clarify, I wrote my comment directed to the OP and didn't see your comment under after I submitted.)

Comment: Or better, no else at all, since both ifs use a return statement

Comment: Its not doing a replace from one http name to the other http name.

Comment: @user1937895 you don't need to do a replace there.. just return the new url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of jQuery's callback-based [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function is

```
.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )
```

Your `if` statements use the first callback argument, `i`, which will always be the index number, but you seem to expect them to be strings. However, the string value of each attribute is in the second callback argument. You probably meant to compare the second argument, `current`.

Furthermore (based on a comment you made), you don't actually want to do an exact match for `old.com`, you want to see if the URL starts with `http://www.old.com`:

```
if ( current.indexOf('http://www.old.com') == 0) { ...
```

Comment: This didn't work. Image doesn't load. Need to have replace to replace old src with new src.

Comment: @user1937895 Edited my answer to guess what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing i and then replacing on current.  Unless current and i are identical, you likely are hitting the wrong condition and not replacing.  Also else() is incorrect and unecessary.

```
a(this).attr('src', function(index, current){
    if ( current == 'http://www.old.com'){
        return 'http://www.new.com';
    }
    else if ( current == 'http://www.older.com'){
        return 'http://www.new.com';
    }
});
```

Edited to remove the replace, thanks @wirey

Comment: I don't even think you need to do a replace.. can't you just return the new url

Comment: I tried this but its not working. The image never loads

Comment: I need the replace cause I have an image http://www.old.com/something/else/older.gif and need to replace it with http://www.new.com/something/else/older.gif

Comment: @user1937895 Tip: `"http://www.old.com/something/else/older.gif" == "http://www.old.com/"` is not true.

Comment: @user1937895 you're going to need some regular expressions in that case, not ==